# Patterns for Reactive Streams Dealing with User Input and Networks

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm using RxKotlin to build out my latest Android app, and I've come up against a familiar issue: how to handle network errors in an Rx-like way.

I have a stream set up for search terms against a `TextView` like this:

```
searchBar
  .queryTextObservable()
  .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
  .map { it.trim() }
  .filter { it.isNotBlank() }
  .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

This is a useful way to listen against changes to text input, so I then extend the code to feed the prepared text into a network request (using the Retrofit library with the RxJava extension) to search against:

```
searchBar
  .queryTextObservable()
  .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
  .map { it.trim() }
  .filter { it.isNotBlank() }
  .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .switchMap { search(it) }
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(...)
```

The problem happens when there's a network error - my entire subscription is cancelled. It seems like I have some options to manage the failure, but none of them seem very clean:

- Have an inner observable after text input is complete that makes the network request
- Use `onErrorResumeNext` and pass a sentinel value

This is obviously not exhaustive, but what is the appropriate pattern(s) to gracefully handle network errors while preserving the stream (and hence the usefulness) of user input from the search bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using operators such as onErrorReturn is a pretty standard approach if you look at reactive patterns which provide a unidirectional data flow such as MVI.

Following such patterns you typically map the state of your network call into an object which represents the state of the call.

A simple example without any MVx patterns would look something like below, where the observable from your RXBinding invokes a call to the API, but instead of just returning the data from the API it returns a state object which can then be rendered on screen.

```
private val disposables = CompositeDisposable()

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    disposables.add(
        RxView.clicks(load_data_button)
            .flatMap { requestData() }
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::renderRequestState)
    )
}

override fun onStop() {
    disposables.clear()
    super.onStop()
}

private fun requestData(): Observable<RequestState> {
    return myApi.requestData()
        .toObservable()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map<RequestState>(RequestState::Success)
        .onErrorReturn(RequestState::Error)
        .startWith(RequestState.InFlight)
}

private fun renderRequestState(requestState: RequestState) {
    when (requestState) {
        RequestState.InFlight -> showProgress()
        is RequestState.Success -> showResult(requestState.result)
        is RequestState.Error -> showError(requestState.error)
    }
}

sealed class RequestState {
    object InFlight : RequestState()
    data class Success(val result: MyData) : RequestState()
    data class Error(val error: Throwable) : RequestState()
}
```

Hannes Dorfmann wrote a great set of articles on the MVI pattern which utilises this approach.

- http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/model-view-intent
- http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/mosby3-mvi-1

Comment: That seems like an excellent approach, and has overlap with some other articles I've read since I've asked this question. From one Chris to another, cheers!

Comment: Give a try to these slides. Maybe these are helpful in the perspective of MVI.
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1pBI5-0G7seYryxyGP40_TpYFslN-Z8FyGi2NIVh4dmY/edit#slide=id.p